# errors in C++ code using std, vector and bitvec and how to take input from user

Tags: c++, input, vector

i posted a question stack overflow here and got this code, i have a few more questions concerning the code, so iv made a separate question for that because the issues are different.

the following code gives me errors as follows (indicated by comments):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
using namespace std;
#include <vector>  

int main() {

string s;
int i;
int j;


//how to take string s as input from user and feed it to the code?
std::vector<uint16_t> bitvec;
unsigned char* cp = s.c_str()+1;
while (*cp) {
   uint16_t bits = *(cp-1)>>8 + *(cp);  // error1
   bitvec.push_back(bits);
 }


 uint32_t sum=0;

for(std::vector<int16_t>::iterator j=bitvec.begin();j!=bitvec.end();++j) { //error2
sum += *j;
uint16_t overflow = sum>>16;  //capture the overflow bit, move it back to lsb
sum &= (1<<16)-1;    //clear the overflow
sum += overflow;     //add it back as lsb
}

//how can i see output of final sum+
```

//error1: std::vector bitvec; //i am getting an errors of 'uint16_t was not declared in scope' and 'tempelate argument not valid' for this line

//error2: ivalid type in declaration before j (what does this mean)

PROBLEM1: how do i take input from user for string s?
why cant i use cout << "enter string" and then use getline(cin,s)? and similarly how can i see output? can i use cout<

PROBLEM2: Am i missing out on any headers here that might be necessary for the code?

Comment: You need `#include <stdint.h>` to get the definitions for `unit16_t` and similar. `#include <cstdint>` is preferable as it doesn't pollute the namesapce but you need to preface each with `std::` or write something like `using std::uint16_t`

Comment: @shuttle87 thanks. but what exactly do i have to preface it with. let me try the way you've put it first i guess.

Comment: @rightfold: sorry i couldnt get what u mean.

Comment: why am i getting this error[Error] conversion from 'std::vector<short unsigned int>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<short unsigned int*, std::vector<short unsigned int> >}' to non-scalar type 'std::vector<short int>::iterator {aka __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<short int*, std::vector<short int> >}' requested

Comment: and also this one: [Error] no match for 'operator!=' in 'j != bitvec.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::end<short unsigned int, std::allocator<short unsigned int> >()'

Comment: You need to learn what these messages are telling you. Basically you made a mistake with the types in the iterator loop and you are now getting this error. Part of the reason I suggest using auto for iterators is because you avoid this type mismatch mistake you made and also helps your code be less boilerplate heavy.

Comment: yes iv used auto in my code too, so that kinda helps. how is the conversion invalid from const char to unsigned character in: unsigned char* cp = s.c_str()+1; does it mean i cannot add them the way i have?

Comment: this is the only error i am getting now, if u could help with this please it would be great

Answer (score 1):

uint16_t is usually defined in  `#include <stdint.h>` on linux.  you need to include this header file.

Comment: how, what is the correct form for inlcluding it as a header file?

Comment: if you are on linux just add to your code #include <stdint.h> in your source file right after #include <vector>.  your current code has an undefined type right now, uint16_t, this type is not part of C++ or C natively, it needs to be defined before being used. if you don't have <stdint.h> available.  just typedef unsigned short uint16_t;  and typedef short int16_t;

Comment: yes this header works for this error. but i still have other errors as commented above

Comment: the types of the vector std::vector<uint16_t> bitvec; does not match std::vector<int16_t>::iterator j=bitvec.begin();.   you will need to change the int16_t to uint16_t or uint16_t to int16_t.  since you are using uint16_t so many other places,  changing int16_t to uint16_t seems better.

Comment: you mean just replace int16_t with uint16_t? how will that change the header files?

Comment: the compiler will not let you assign the iterator returned by bitvec.begin() to an iterator of a different type.  std::vector<int16_t>::iterator j is of the wrong type.  it needs to be std::vector<uint16_t>::iterator j.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler can't find the types you are using because you haven't included the right header file that defines them.

Try this:

```
#include <cstdint> //uint16_t and similar defined in here

std::vector<std::uint16_t> bitvec;
unsigned char* cp = s.c_str()+1;
while (*cp) {
   std::uint16_t bits = *(cp-1)>>8 + *(cp);  // error1
   bitvec.push_back(bits);
 }
```

Note that `#include <cstdint>` does not pull these type into the global namespace (this is why it is preferred to `#include<stdint.h>` and I think this is why stdint.h is depreciated now) but this means you have to put `std::` in front of each type. Alternatively you can bring them into scope with a using statement like so `using std::uint16_t`. You have a `using namespace std` in your code so this will automatically do that for you.

Also I think you will find the iterator code much nicer if you use auto like so:

```
for(auto j = bitvec.begin(); j != bitvec.end(); ++j) { 
    sum += *j;
    std::uint16_t overflow = sum>>16;  //capture the overflow bit, move it back to lsb
    sum &= (1<<16)-1;    //clear the overflow
    sum += overflow;     //add it back as lsb
}
```

Comment: #include <cstdint> gives me this error:  #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.

Comment: do i have some sort of compiler limitation. i am using dev C++ version 5.5.2

Comment: what about the for statement? am i supposed to use 'using' inside that too?

Comment: Pass in the flag -std=c++11 flag when compiling to get access to `cstdint` otherwise include `stdint.h`

Comment: i used auto. get this error now: [Error] no match for 'operator!=' in 'j != bitvec.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::end<short unsigned int, std::allocator<short unsigned int> >()'

Comment: The code as it appears here compiles fine on my system, I'm using gcc 4.6.

Comment: yes there is some problem with the support as you pointed out. but i dont know how to correct it. how should i enable it with gnu++11 or -std=c++11? i dont know how to.

Comment: The input and output problem still remains though...how do i take user input and get o/p. same way as i specified right? or is that different here too?